Special Form of Constructible Real Numbers
I am thinking of a special form of constructible real numbers: a linear combination (with rational coefficients) of products of iterated square roots of prime numbers. The followings are examples of the forms of some specific numbers. (I used the general root symbol to represent iterated square roots for convenience.)

$\sqrt{5 + \sqrt{24}} = \sqrt 2 + \sqrt 3$
$\sqrt{4 + \sqrt{18}} = \sqrt[4] 2 + \sqrt 2 \sqrt[4] 2$
$\sqrt{5 + \sqrt{45}} = \dfrac 1 2 \sqrt 2 \sqrt[4] 5 + \dfrac 1 2 \sqrt 2 \sqrt 5 \sqrt[4] 5$

However, I have no idea to find such form of $\cos \biggl(\dfrac{2}{17} \pi\biggr)$ which is constructible. Will any constructible real numbers have this special form?

How about $\sqrt{\sqrt 2 + \sqrt 3}$?

What do you mean by "consecutive"? What's consecutive about $(1/2)\sqrt2\root4\of5+(1/2)\sqrt2\sqrt5\root4\of5$?

@lhf That is also what I'm struggling for.

@GerryMyerson I wanted to refer to something like $\sqrt{\ }, \sqrt{\sqrt{\ }}, \sqrt{\sqrt{\sqrt{\ }}}, \dots$, and for convenience, I used $\sqrt[4] 5$ instead of $\sqrt{\sqrt 5}$.

OK. I think the word you're looking for is "iterated".

@GerryMyerson Thank you for correcting my English!
